# AWS SQS add a POST request and POST data in queue

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How can I add a POST request with POST data in AWS SQS queue? Generally I want to hit an endpoint with POST data using SQS from it's queue and also need a callback when endpoint returns a response from that endpoint.

For example:

- endpoint: https://example.com/endpoint
- POST data: `{data:data}`

I want to hit these endpoints from SQS queue.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest an architecture for this. It is basically you have to create an endpoint which publishes data to a SNS(simple notification service) topic and that can be a POST request. So that SNS topic will be subscribed to an AWS SQS queue and it(SNS topic) will publish that data into the SQS queue. After that you can do what ever you have to do with queue data. As an example if you process the queue data using EC2 instance then after processing it you should send the processed/output data back to the endpoint. In that scenario you can create a web hook/AWS IOT topic which and publish your data to that topic. So that after you post your data to the SNS topic in the initial stage your request will be closed, and you should create a subscription for this AWS IOT topic where you will get the processed/output data of your initial request.